# ffmpeg 5.1 build fail with --enable-shared ( libavcodec\avcodec-59.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

Installation : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC
https://www.roxlu.com/2019/062/compiling-ffmpeg-with-x264-on-windows-10-using-msvc
Env: win10 + vs2019 + MSYS
ffmpeg version: 5.1

using --enable-shared will show the error when 'make -j4'
And my MSYS terminal is frozen.

Error:

```
codec/xbmdec.o libavcodec/xbmenc.o libavcodec/xface.o libavcodec/xfacedec.o libavcodec/xfaceenc.o libavcodec/xiph.o libavcodec/xl.o libavcodec/xma_parser.o libavcodec/xpmdec.o libavcodec/xsubdec.o libavcodec/xsubenc.o libavcodec/xvididct.o libavcodec/xwddec.o libavcodec/xwdenc.o libavcodec/xxan.o libavcodec/y41pdec.o libavcodec/y41penc.o libavcodec/ylc.o libavcodec/yop.o libavcodec/yuv4dec.o libavcodec/yuv4enc.o libavcodec/log2_tab.o libavcodec/reverse.o > libavcodec/avcodec-59.def
LD      libavcodec/avcodec-59.dll
LINK : libavcodec\avcodec-59.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
   Creating library libavcodec/avcodec.lib and object libavcodec/avcodec.exp
```

Until I crtl + c

```
make: *** Deleting file 'libavcodec/avcodec-59.dll'
make: unlink: libavcodec/avcodec-59.dll: Device or resource busy
make: *** [ffbuild/library.mak:119: libavcodec/avcodec-59.dll] Interrupt
```

Comment: Title is not the question. Please edit your post to make it more clear, and to add any further information that will help us understand it and help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do get a frozen terminal when using nasm instead of yasm. If I remove nasm, I can compile correctly:

```
pacman -R nasm
```

You can get more details here: https://gardinal.net/x264-and-ffmpeg-compilation-for-windows/